# drawing app won't use randomly generated CGfloats, but will use static CGfloats for color generation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm writing a simple drawing app where every time the user puts their finger down to draw, a different color is used. If I set my "red, green, blue" values to specific values then it draws like it should, but when I attempt to use a CGFloat randomizer function the app seems to ignore user input. I verified the randomizer function is working simply by having the randomized values print out when they're generated.

In the code below if I comment out

```
red = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)
green = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)
blue = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)
```

and use the default values of 0 for red, green, blue in setStrokeColor, then the drawing app draws normally using black as the stroke color. If I uncomment the randomizers then the app doesn't display anything when I attempt to draw. The limits for the randomizers are set correctly (and verified in print out messages), so I'm not sure why setStrokeColor is ignoring the values.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!

var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
var red: CGFloat = 0
var green: CGFloat = 0
var blue: CGFloat = 0
var brushWidth: CGFloat = 30.0
var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
var swiped = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false

    red = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)
    green = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)
    blue = randomCGFloat(min: 1, max: 254)

    print("red: \(red)")
    print("green: \(green)")
    print("blue: \(blue)")

    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)

    }
}

func drawLineFrom(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)

    mainImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.move(to: fromPoint)
    context?.addLine(to: toPoint)

    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.strokePath()

    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    mainImageView.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        drawLineFrom(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        // draw a single point
        self.drawLineFrom(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint)
    }
}

func randomCGFloat(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return round(CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) * (max - min) + min)
}
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red/green/blue values you pass to setStrokeColor need to be between 0.0 and 1.0 not from 1 to 254 as in your code.

Comment: Thanks! you were correct!